# Unable to Authorize Salesforce org using SFDX : Trailhead as it shows API is disabled

Tags: lightning-web-components, vs-code

I am doing the Salesforce Trailhead Lightning Web Components. After I've created a project, I'm trying to "Authorize an org", but keep on receiving an error saying "API is disabled for this user" as shown below. 
Ps- I've installed all the necessary extensions required for creating the lightning web component.
Can anyone help me out to solve this problem? 
[image]

[image]

Comment: This seems like a permission issue. Somehow API access is disabled for your user. Please check your user's configuration. https://support.geckoboard.com/hc/en-us/articles/217148797-How-do-I-enable-API-access-in-Salesforce-

Comment: Also, this error can occur if you are trying to Oauth Login to PE or GE orgs. Please check if you are trying it on the correct org.

Comment: @rahulgawale Thanks for the reply. Can you please guide me a bit about where can I check that which org I'm trying to Oauth login into?

Comment: @blank Thanks for the reply. Actually I was not using geckoboard support while building the lightning web component. 
I was simply referring to this link for creating it, is the geckoboard support mandatory to build lightning web components?https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/quick-start-lightning-web-components/create-a-hello-world-lightning-web-component?trail_id=build-lightning-web-components

Comment: You don't have to use it. It's just the first link I got with the instruction how to turn on the API access for a user

Comment: @LavanyaGaur I think you should first try what Blank has said, if it does not work then you can check, you can check your org edition by going to `Setup -> Company information -> Search "Organization Edition" in the page`.

Comment: @blank The API access for the user is already enabled, I just checked but still the same problem.
Link to the image - https://postimg.cc/8fWrsjWh

Comment: @rahulgawale I'm using the developer edition org which I guess is alright. But still the same problem.

Comment: Also, when I run the command ` lsof -i tcp:1717 ` in order to kill the process at the port, in the result I don 't get any process id, basically I get an empty result. Any idea why this is happening?